# Is it possible to use 'in' keyword to filter on ListProperty(item_type=datetime.date)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have google app engine Event model. I need to find events in some date range. It could be [15.02.2012, 15.03.2012, 18.04.2013]. But when I'm searching I get exception.

Model class:

```
class Event(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    dates = db.ListProperty(item_type=datetime.date)

dates = [datetime.date.today(), datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days = 7), datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days = 14), datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days = 24)]
```

Here is my query:

```
# exception
query = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM Event WHERE dates in :dates', dates=dates)
```

This code is without exception but with wrong results:

```
# 0 results, it's wrong
query = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM Event WHERE dates in :dates', dates=[datetime.datetime.now()])
```

Works, but I need 'in':

```
query = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM Event WHERE dates = DATE(2012, 1, 23)')
```

The same exception:

```
query = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM Event WHERE dates in [DATE(2012, 1, 23)]')
```

Description of exception:

```
ERROR    2012-01-23 13:38:28,335 base.py:117] error: code='internal_server_error', message="Unsupported type for property  : <type 'datetime.date'>"
ERROR    2012-01-23 13:38:28,345 base.py:119] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\project\eventinarea\eventinarea\handler\event.py", line 12, in get
    tags=self.param('tags')
  File "D:\project\eventinarea\eventinarea\logic\event.py", line 20, in search_events
    logging.info(query.count())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\db\__init__.py", line 2059, in count
    raw_query = self._get_query()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\db\__init__.py", line 2633, in _get_query
    self._cursor, self._end_cursor)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\gql\__init__.py", line 326, in Bind
    query.update(enumerated_query)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\datastore.py", line 1723, in update
    self.__setitem__(filter, value)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\datastore.py", line 1666, in __setitem__
    datastore_types.ValidateProperty(' ', value, read_only=True)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\datastore_types.py", line 1480, in ValidateProperty
    'Unsupported type for property %s: %s' % (name, v.__class__))
BadValueError: Unsupported type for property  : <type 'datetime.date'>
```

Comment: it's only example of code. I really need to use 'in' with the list of dates as parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# 0 results, it's wrong 
query = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM Event WHERE dates in :dates', dates=[datetime.datetime.now()])
```

The reason this produces no results is that you are passing in `now()` (which includes both year/month/day and hour/min/sec/microsec), whereas the date of your entity is just the date (year/month/day).

Something like the following would probably work:

```
today = datetime.datetime.today()
today_date = datetime.datetime(year = today.year, month = today.month, day = today.day)
query = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM Event WHERE dates in :dates', dates = [today_date])
```

I think the clue for why your original query fails is this:

```
BadValueError: Unsupported type for property  : <type 'datetime.date'>
```

The query is expecting `datetime.datetime` objects, but you are passing in `datetime.date` objects.

Something like the following may work:

```
today = datetime.datetime.today()
today_date = datetime.datetime(year = today.year, month = today.month, day = today.day)
dates = [today_date, today_date + datetime.timedelta(days = 7), today_date + datetime.timedelta(days = 14), today_date + datetime.timedelta(days = 24)]
query = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM Event WHERE dates in :dates', dates = dates)
```

Comment: Yeah, the exception is because GQL doesn't like date, only datetime. A date is represented in the datastore as a datetime with the time set to all zeros. So if you can create datetime objects corresponding to your requested dates but with the time set to zero it should work.